# the bar chart of power bi doesn't apear the data

Tags: powerbi

I have created a column to estimate a rate by country but the diagramm appears only three countries with same rate which obviously is mistaken . Which is the mistake?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SxNi.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7opzg.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you have a divide by zero case that causes an "infinite" value to be calculated for France, Germany and Mexico.

However, you do not provide meaningful sample data or other relevant data such as what formula you have used in your calculated column `rate` (which is apparently giving you bad values).